# relationships for storage of working hours in a database divided into multiple points of sale

Tags: laravel, database, database-design

I'm creating a management system for the company in Laravel. I'm doing the part that concerns the management of employee schedules and our various sales points.

I have a user table, a front offices table and a time table Schedules with these columns:

- ID
- start_time and end_time are the start and end times
- day_of_week is the day of the week in integer
- type_day is the type of day such as holidays, working days, etc.
- morning_or_afternoon indicates whether the time is for the morning or the afternoon; simplifies some things  but could be removed
- valid_from and valid_through are the validity period
- priority; if in the same validity period, I have a timetable of the same type already entered I only take into consideration the one with the highest priority

A user can have multiple hours (e.g. working hours, overtime hours, exit permit, etc.) in a day and a counter usually has a specific timetable but sometimes an employee is missing or you decide to keep the counter closed that day. Then I will have more than one schedule.

A user will be at a counter at a certain time of day and there can be multiple users at a counter.

I will need to be able to pull out the hours for each employee and each branch, know which branch a user is in or which users are in the branch, count vacations, sick days, etc...

I'm not sure which table relationship to use for what I need to do, for example, whether to use the polymorphic relationship inside the Schedules table or create a many-to-many relationship, especially what makes me unsure is if I do a one-to-many relationship how can I then understand which frontoffice the user is in? Do I create another many-to-many relationship between the front office, users and schedules? Then isn't it better to just create a pivot table? If I make a pivot table what do I put id_user, id_schedules_user, id_frontoffices_ and id_schedules_frontoffices?

Comment: "Where are you 1st stuck, following what published method? [ask] [Help]" Right now you are just asking for a textbook to be (re)written with a bespoke tutorial. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Dozens of (good) (and bad) published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying are online free in pdf & html. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts or videos.) Free courses are online. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.)

Comment: Please: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate question. Again: Please act on the feedback.